# Memory management issue google maps on UITableViewCell in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-maps-sdk-ios

The way I have implemented is :

I have a nib: UITableViewCell, and there is a google map implemented with two markers and a path between two markers.

When I run the program with sample 8 cells on UItableView, it is crashing some times, by saying **app exit due to a memory management issue**

In nib file **"BookingHistoryTableViewCell"**:

```
import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleMaps
import GoogleMapsCore
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleToolboxForMac

class BookingHistoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.bottomView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.bottomView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.bottomView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.bottomView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    //main gate : 6.795046, 79.900768
    func setupMap(){
        let lat = 6.797222
        let lon = 79.902028
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 17.0)
        let googleMapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mapView.bounds, camera: camera)
//        googleMapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
//        googleMapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
//        googleMapView.settings.zoomGestures = false
//        googleMapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
//        googleMapView.accessibilityScroll(UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.left)
//        googleMapView.mapStyle(withFilename: "googleMapsStyle02", andType: "json")
        self.mapView.addSubview(googleMapView)
        //(googleMapView, at: 0)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        marker.title = "Main Title"
        marker.snippet = "Deescription"
        marker.map = googleMapView
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //self.setupMap()
    }

    override func layoutIfNeeded() {
        super.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.setupMap()
    }

    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        super.setNeedsLayout()
//        self.setupMap()
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Then on tableViews at **MyBookingsViewController** :

```
viewDidLoad(){
  self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BookingHistoryTableViewCell" , bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BookingHistoryTableViewCell")
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30
}
```

then as an extension I have table controls :

```
extension MyBookingsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookingHistoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingHistoryTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row number : \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, handler) in
            print("tapped on Edit : \(indexPath.row)")
        }

        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
            print("tapped on Delete : \(indexPath.row)")
        }

        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 183/255, green: 183/255, blue: 183/255, alpha: 0.9)
        editAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_edit_white")
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 251/255, green: 86/255, blue: 92/255, alpha: 0.9)
        deleteAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_delete_white")
        let configuaration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
        configuaration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
        return configuaration
    }

}
```

This is kinda needed and in real life application there will be 100 of cells like this. is there any way to render only visible cells to the display area or some method to save the memory?

Comment: Need to look at your code. Show us your relevant code.

Comment: @pkc456 please look at the code : I have edit the Question

Comment: Why you are not calling `setupMap` method from `awakeFromNib()`?

Comment: @pkc456 because : map layout will not fit in to the UIView, when I call it in the `awakeFromNib()`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be not to implement a map per cell. I'm having the same trouble, but the difference is that I'm using Apple Maps. The Apple MapView allows to show different things (Buildings, 3D View, location...) If you have some kind of this elements in Google Maps, try to deactivate it.

In my app, the using RAM changed from 300 to 165.

[Elements to deactivation MKMapView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srOPV.png)